# i am trying to search files from folder level but i am getting some issues

Tags: php, regex

i have created one search box with datepicker my folder structure like `data2/mysqldump/050516` and into this folder i have files with name of : `phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2` i want to search file with only first name like `"phpdev11_"` and with full name like `"phpdev11_test1"` i uses regular expression but it's not work like this result . my code is

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data2/mysqldump/';
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$flattened = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$files = new RegexIterator($flattened, '#^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/]+)+/[^/]+\.(?:sql|bz2)$#Di');
foreach($files as $file) {
echo $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/\n]+)+/phpdev11(?:_test1)?(?:\.(?:sql|bz2))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/lV3oW8/2) can help?

Comment: thank you for replay but it's not work for me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below works for me,
I have changed your regex to:

> ## ^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!.Trash)[^/]+)+/'.$fullName.'.(?:sql).(?:bz2)$#i

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);



$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = __DIR__;

// $firstName = null;
// $lastName = null;
$firstName = 'phpdev11_';
$lastName = 'test1';

$defaultNamePattern = '[^/]+?';
if ($firstName) {
    $fullName = $firstName;
} else {
    $fullName = $defaultNamePattern;
}

if ($lastName) {
    $fullName .= $lastName;
} else {
    $fullName .= $defaultNamePattern;
}

$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data2/mysqldump/';

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$flattened = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

$regex = '#^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/]+)+/'.$fullName.'\.(?:sql)\.(?:bz2)$#i';
$files = new RegexIterator($flattened, $regex);
echo $regex . "\n";

foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Directory structure:

```
data2/
└── mysqldump
    ├── 050516
    │   ├── phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2
    │   ├── phpdev12_test1.sql.bz2
    │   ├── phpdev12_test2.sql.bz2
    │   └── test.txt
    ├── 050517
    │   ├── phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2
    │   └── phpdev12_test1.sql.bz2
    └── .Trash
        └── phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2
```

Output:

```
#^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/]+)+/phpdev11_test1\.(?:sql)\.(?:bz2)$#i
/var/www/apps/misc/phptut/trash/php/data2/mysqldump/050517/phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2
/var/www/apps/misc/phptut/trash/php/data2/mysqldump/050516/phpdev11_test1.sql.bz2
```